# convert the content of XML string (which i sXML itseself) into a new XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

****Source XML File****

```
<TEXT_String xmlns="http://danfoss.com/xi/BCM">
![CDATA[<Document><BkToCstmrStmt><GrpHdr><MsgId>a</MsgId><CreDtTm>2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z</CreDtTm></GrpHdr></BkToCstmrStmt></Document>]
</TEXT_String>
```

****Desired XML Output****

```
<Document>
 <BkToCstmrStmt>
  <GrpHdr>
    <MsgId>a</MsgId>
    <CreDtTm>2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z</CreDtTm>
   </GrpHdr>
  </BkToCstmrStmt>
</Document>
```

I only manganed to the get the string value, without Tags and with the CDATA

```
![CDATA[a2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z]
```

Any ideas.

Br Frank Hinrichsen

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:BCM="http://danfoss.com/xi/BCM">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="BCM:TEXT_String/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*Error: Ambiguous rule match for /TEXT_String/Document[1]/BkToCstmrStmt[1]/GrpHdr[1]/MsgId[1]/text()[1]
Matches both "text()" on line 11 of file:stylesheet.xsl
and "node()" on line 5 of file:stylesheet.xsl*" Courtesy of Saxon.

Comment: I have not noticed this until you posted a comment. Edited my post above. thanks

Comment: @michael.hor257k I use an online tool when I'm out of home and yes, it indeed does not display errors if they do not lead to complete failure. You were right, I'll delete my comment in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your source document is that the CDATA markup is incorrect. As a result, the strings `![CDATA[` and `]` are just that: text nodes, children of the root `<TEXT_String>` element. Applying an identity transform template to the XML will result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEXT_String xmlns="http://danfoss.com/xi/BCM">
![CDATA[<Document>
      <BkToCstmrStmt>
         <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>a</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z</CreDtTm>
         </GrpHdr>
      </BkToCstmrStmt>
   </Document>]
</TEXT_String>
```

Adding a template to suppress any text nodes that are children of the root element would probably be a good solution. Or, since it seems you don't want the root element included in the output at all, just suppress it entirely:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- not required for the example input -->
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```